# Access guild with createGuild()

Tags: java, discord-jda

I want to make a function that makes the bot create a guild and send me the invite link, if I type `!makeserver`. However, `guild.getSystemChannel()` does not work in the callback. My JDA version is 4.4.0_352.

```java
if (message[0].equalsIgnoreCase("!makeserver")) {
            if (message.length < 2) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("Name the server!").queue();
                return;
            }
            String serverName = message[1];
            event.getJDA().createGuild(serverName).queue(guild -> {
                GuildChannel defaultChannel = guild.getSystemChannel();// this code didn't work 
                defaultChannel.createInvite().queue(invite -> {
                    String inviteUrl = invite.getUrl();
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("I made the server and send the link!\n" + inviteUrl).queue();
                }, error -> {
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("Fail to send link.").queue();
                    if (error instanceof Exception) {
                        Exception e = (Exception) error;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }, error -> {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("Fail to make the server .").queue();
                if (error instanceof Exception) {
                    Exception e = (Exception) error;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback does not provide the guild, you need to use the [`GuildJoinEvent`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/guild/GuildJoinEvent.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for Help! but i still don't know what you mean. you mean i have to use GuildjoinEvent to make server?? and i have another Question i can't use Guild classes  i checked dependency and version and i imported net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Guild ...